# Finding elements (neighbors) in a representation of a sparse graph (matrix)

Tags: c, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse graph that I am representing as an adjacency matrix (100k by 100k or bigger), stored as an array of edges. An example with a (non-sparse) 4 by 4 matrix:

```
0 7
4 0

example_array = [ [7,1,2], [4,2,1] ]
```

E.g. [4,1,2] says that there is a directed edge from node 1 to node 2 with the value/weight 4. In matrix lingo, this is essentially [ value, row, column ].

Also, this "array of edges" will be sorted by the first element. In the example above, after sorting, the array becomes,

```
example_array = [ [4,2,1], [7,1,2] ]
```

**Problem**

For a certain value `i`, need to find all elements in this sorted "array of edges" with second value equal to `i`. i.e. Find `j` such that `example_array[j][1] = i`.

My preliminary implementation of this is to simply iterate all elements in the array, comparing the second value of each element with `i`. This is computationally expensive because there might still be a lot (e.g. 500k) of elements to loop through.

**Question**

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I do not mind using a different representation of the matrix/graph. I am writing this in C.

**Additional Information**

This is essentially finding all the neighbors of a node `i`, and their edge weights. i.e. Finding all directed edges from `i` to another node, from the edge list.

Comment: Is this an undirected graph?  is each edge represented twice as in: [4,2,1] and [4,1,2]?

Comment: @ajon - Directed and weighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use sparse Compressed Row Storage for that purpose. Briefly, you store the matrix row by row, so you don't need to keep two (row,column) indices. Instead you keep a row pointer, i.e., an array which tells you where a given row starts in memory. Then you keep the column vector (col_ind), which tells you the position of the non-zero column in that row, and you store the corresponding value (val). This cuts down the storage requirements, but also speeds up matrix searches, since the col_ind for every row are sorted. So, you have a direct access to every matrix row, and you can quickly localize entries within every row using bisection, or any other sorted list search of your choice.

CRS matrix can be quickly created using insertion into sorted lists, or e.g. bucket sort if you have explicitly constructed (i,j) coordinates of every matrix entry. In MATLAB you can do this using 'sparse' function. If you don't want to code it yourself and need a library, have a look at [SuiteSparse by Tim Davis](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/).

For a brief description of the CRS format look e.g. [here](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node373.html), but there are thousands of other sources for it.

**Edit** You can do what you need easily with a modified CRS storage. First, you need to create the matrix by sorting the columns within each row by value instead of the column index, as is usually done. This means that the smallest value for each row is stored as the first entry in every row. Then, to find the globally smallest value, you search the first entry of all rows (O(n) complexity). Knowing that you obtain the corresponding column index in constant time by reading the first column index in the row containing the smallest value. You can do all that because you know where the rows start in memory thanks to your row pointer.

You can have a look at [this code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/milamin/files/). It is a set of mex files for matlab implemented in C. What you are interested in is sparse_create_mex.c. It creates the sparse matrix structure using iterative addition of (i, j, value) into sorted lists. You would need to modify the sorted lists a bit - right now they are implemented for integer column indices and double values. Since the sorted lists are implemented as macro templates, you only need to declare a new sorted list type (see sorted_list.h and sorted_list_templates.h).

Comment: Can CRS representation be sorted by value? i.e. List the values of the first row from smallest to largest. The column index and row pointer would have to be adjusted according I suppose. Are there examples of how I could do this? (I googled)

Comment: @Legendre Usually the values are not of main interest in sparse storage, but rather the column indices within rows. But of course nothing can stop you from sorting by value if you wish. The only issue then is adding new/updating existing non-zero entries in the matrix. If your column indices are **not** sorted, to add a new non-zero entry you simply add it to the end of row list. However, if you want to update the existing value, you will need to go through all column indices to see, if the value is already there. But you surely can adjust it to your needs.

Comment: @Legendre I would definitely advise this rather than some linked list approach. I talk order of magnitude in performance difference at least. I am not sure about examples. CRS is very popular, so you can find tons of papers about it. What kind of examples would you want?

Comment: Given a sparse matrix, I need to pick the entry with the smallest non-zero value, and if it is in the j-th column, find all the non-zero entry of row j. Viewing the matrix as a directed weighted graph, I would be finding the smallest edge weight, find the node (call it "v") it is pointing to, then find the non-zero edge weights of "v". In my example, the smallest non-zero value is 4, in column 1, then the non-zero entry of column 1 is 7. I need to do this for the next smallest, and the next and so on.

Comment: Are there examples on sorting CRS? Been googling and didn't see any. For the previously mentioned purpose, I would need to sort the first array (the array containing the values). But this would mess up the column_index and row pointers (I need to tell which column + row the value came from after sorting).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing the representation then it would be less computationally intensive if you sorted by the second element because then you could just step through and once you found the an element larger than i you would be done.  In the worst case the best possible algorithm is O(n), but if you sort by second element then on expectation this would run in n/2 time.

Comment: I need the edge list sorted by first element. After that I need to do the finding. I meant I don't mind switching from an edge-list representation to something else. (will still need to sort the weights/entries though)

Comment: if the nodes are sorted by 2nd element two binary searches will be enough to find the range of cells. total complexity n*log n (sort) + 2*log n = n*log n

Comment: n*log n is for std qsort- if the data is too much to fit in memory might need to use merge sort

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using pointers?

```
// A list of edges emanating from one node.
typedef struct {
    int weight;    
    int nodeId;    // The target node
    Edge *next;    // Next edge in the list
} Edge;

typedef struct {
    int nodeId;
    Edge *edges;   // This node's edge list
} Node;

// Now just store all your nodes in an array
Node *example_array[MAX_NODES];
```

When you insert an edge on a node, you do an ordered insert on it's `edges` list by weight.  Now, to answer your question about finding all edges beginning at some node, you simply look that node up in your array and traverse its edges list.  The bonus is that you visit its edges in sorted order without having to search through any other parts of the graph.

Comment: Is this what you are referring to: cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/graph/linked?